# Microphone not working when a call occures

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I m trying to record a voice using Microphone API in WP7/WP8.
Every thing is working fine when i use it to record a normal voice, but when i use it when a call is answered the application is running well. but when i playback that recorded voice the whole recording is empty, there is no sound at all.

what happened with the microphone in this case?

here is the code which i m using

```
  microphone.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
  microphone.Start();


        void micro_BufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            audioBuffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(microphone.BufferDuration)];
            microphone.GetData(audioBuffer);               
            currentRecordingStream.Write(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.Length);         
        }
```

Comment: Did you add `ID_CAP_MICROPHONE` Capability?

Comment: yes i have added all the required capabilities..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't record a call with the microphone in your app. When a call is activated, the call app on the phone take control of the Microphone and the sound is directed to it, not to your application.

Comment: i m recording the sound when the call is in background and my application is in front...in that case also will it work like you said...